# Rails help pre-populate data - Token input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I am trying to pre-populate data to a token input field.

But nothing gets pre-populated in my edit view.

I have followed this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields

My controller:

```
class Admin::TagsController < Admin::AdminController
layout 'admin'
def index
    @title = 'asdsadas'
    @kategoris = Tag.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @kategoris.map(&:attributes) }
    end
end
end
```

My application.js:

```
// Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
// This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults

$(function() {
  $("#konkurrancer_tag_tokens").tokenInput("http://localhost:3000/admin/tags.json", {
    crossDomain: false,
    prePopulate: $("#konkurrancer_tag_tokens").data("pre"),
    theme: "facebook"
  });
});
```

My edit view:

```
<h1>Editing kategori</h1>
<%= simple_form_for(@konkurrancer, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @konkurrancer.id }) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :tag_tokens, :label => 'Tags', "data-pre" => @konkurrancer.tags.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
<%= f.button :submit, :value => 'Edit konkurrence' %>
<% end %>
```

Token field output:

```
<div class="input string optional">
<label for="konkurrancer_tag_tokens" class="string optional"> Tags</label>
<ul class="token-input-list-facebook"><li class="token-input-input-token-facebook">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="outline: medium none; width: 30px;">
<tester style="position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px; width: auto; font-size: 13.3333px; font-family: MS Shell Dlg; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; white-space: nowrap;"></tester></li></ul>
<input type="text" size="50" name="konkurrancer[tag_tokens]" id="konkurrancer_tag_tokens" class="string optional" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your data-pre with input_html in your edit view:

```
:input_html => {"data-pre" => @konkurrancer.tags.map(&:attributes).to_json }
```

*** You're using simple_form while the railscasts isn't.